# Is union of two subspace a subspace too?

Tags: vector-spaces

Assume that $W$ and $V$ are two subspace of $X$. Is their union a subspace of $X$ too? I think it is not true unless under certain conditions but I do not know what conditions...

Comment: What conditions have you tried?

Comment: Hint for you to prove: $\;W\cup V\;$ is a subspace of $\;X\;$ iff $\;W\subset V\;$ **or** $\;V\subset W\;$ .

Comment: (A search for ["union of two subspaces"](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=union+of+two+subspaces) produces at least six questions on this topic, with many answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that
$$W\subseteq V \text{ or } V\subseteq W.$$The sufficiency is clear.
If $W\bigcup V$ is a subspace, suppose that there exist an $x\in W-V$, and a $y\in V-W$. Then we have $x+y\notin W\bigcup V$, contradiction! Hence, either $x$ or $y$ does not exist, which leads to the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

No, union is not vector subspace in general (e.g. $\{y=x\}\cup \{y=-x\}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$... direct sum $W\oplus V$ is a vector subspace).